# Removing the viewController programmatically from the navigation stack in ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I want to clear my navigation stack which has two view controllers, before pushing the 3rd new ViewController. I am doing the following:

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllerArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];

for (int i = 0; i < [viewControllerArray count]; i++) {
      [viewControllerArray removeObjectAtIndex:i]; 
      //here the [viewControllerArray count] is 2,but loop is iterated only once.
}

self.navigationController.viewControllers=viewControllerArray;

NSLog(@"View Controller Array %@",[self.navigationController viewControllers])
//This will print null which I assume is correct.
```

Then I push the new ViewController as followed:

```
  DetailViewController *detailView=[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
```

But my new view is not getting pushed, instead the topmost view present in the navigation stack is getting displayed. I feel this is very strange because , I am already removed the ViewControllers and printing it in NSLog, which shows null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove one view controller before pushing the third view and remove the second view controller from third view controller. Removing more than one viewController using loop may cause error sometimes.

Comment: If I do it in the DetailViewController then,[viewControllerArray removeObjectAtIndex:i] will remove the DetailViewController as well

Comment: check the condition in for loop in my answer. It is     [viewControllerArray count]-1

Comment: If it is not working, try to remove one view controller before pushing the third view and remove the second view controller from third view controller. Removing more than one viewController using loop may cause  error sometimes. I don't know why.

Comment: you are right.Removing more than one viewController using loop doesn't provide the expected result . Its really strange. Thanks for the help :).I was struggling from long time.Please, add your comment to the answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: Removing the  previous viewControllers from the stack in your DetailViewController class doesn't make any difference. I have accepted it because of the second part

Comment: @Raj I have removed that part from my answer. Thank you..:)

Answer (score 3):

```
DetailViewController *detailView = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];    
NSMutableArray *viewControllerArray = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[viewControllerArray removeAllObjects];
[viewControllerArray addObject:detailView];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllerArray animated:YES];
```

Try this.